# How Can I route From One page to another when its route are in different file

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

i'm using React.js my routes file are as follow -> app.js have main 3 routes

- Routes 1 (more routes inside )

```js
<Switch>
      <Route path='/auth' component={Auth}/>
      <Route path='/panel' component={Panel}/>
      <Route path='/show' component={Show}/>
    </Switch>
```

- Routes 2 (more routes inside )

```js
<Switch>
      <Route exact path='/panel/products' component={Products}/>
      <R<Route exact path='/panel/products1' component={Products1}/>
      <Route exact path='/panel/products2' component={Products2}/>
</Switch>
```

- Routes 3 (more routes inside )

```js
<Switch>
  <Route exact path='/show/message' component={Message}/>
</Switch>
```

now, when i try to jump from route 2 child route using this.props.push('/show/message') to route 3 it's not working
it just redirect me to default route of Routes 2

> It's Working Fine When Im routing inside the route 2 
>   ,is there Any Solution???

Comment: Can you show some of your code and tell us what version of react-router you are currently using?

Comment: "react-router-dom": "4.3.1",

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that the `push()` method is called using `this.props.push()`? Anyway, try wrapping your component with `withRouter` HOC so it can receive props such as `match`, `location`, and `history`. Then, use the `history` prop to push a new entry to the history stack.
For example, using your `Products2` component, try this code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';
class Products2 extends Component {
   render(){
     const { match, location, history } = this.props;
     return (
         <button onClick={() => history.push('/show/message')}>Redirect to third route</button>
     );
   }
}

export default withRouter(Products2);
```

Another approach you can try is to pass the props of the parent route to the child route.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
//import here your child components

class Panel extends Component {
   render(){
     return (
     <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/panel/products' render={() => <Products parentProps={this.props} />}/>
        <Route exact path='/panel/products1' component={Products1}/>
        <Route exact path='/panel/products2' component={Products2}/>
     </Switch>
     );
   }
}

export default Panel;
```

Then in the `Products` component, use `this.props.parentProps.history.push('/show/message')`

Comment: i try, but it still redirect me to default route,here a thing when i Comment my default route, the URL changed to 'http://XXX/show/message' but its not redirect me, until i press enter

Comment: I added an alternate approach. Check it out.